# Proper display converted SQL resultset into JSON

Tags: java, json, postgresql, jdbc, resultset

I'm trying to implement java method for web service that should retrieve data from table and return the result in json format. For this I use json_agg() function that converts query result into json which I want to display, but it displays in wrong format so far. Here is the method itself:

```
public String GetRowsFromTable() throws SQLException {

    Connection connection = null;
    String result = "";
    try {
        connection = Connection.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT json_agg(table1) FROM table");
        ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
        result += rs;
        System.out.println(rs);
    } catch (SQLException sqlex) {
        sqlex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        connection.close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

The console displays the following result:

```
org.postgresql.jdbc.PgResultSet@5179f609
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *but it displays in wrong format so far* this means absolutely nothing.

Comment: also that is the default output of `.toString()` on `Object` and not the correct thing to call on `ResultSet`, just look at the source code for `ResultSet`, it just does the default on `Object`. I think you need to read the documentation on what you are trying to do, or again if you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through the `ResultSet` and retrieve each *column*. The `ResultSet` instance is **not** your actual result it's a container for the result. Your query returns one column, so you can access the content of that through the index 1 (JDBC column indexes start at 1, not 0 as usual in Java). To move the result set to the next row you need to use `next()`

```
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
}
```

Typically you would use a `while()` loop to iterate over all rows in the `ResultSet` but your query will only return a single row due to the aggregation so that's not necessary. Are you sure you *really* want **all** rows of the table as a single huge JSON document. What if the table contains a million rows?

This is all explained in the Java JDBC tutorial:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/getstart/GettingStartedTOC.fm.html